# Does chewing gum break intermittent fasting

Tags: intermittent-fasting

> Intermittent fasting is a technique where you adjust your eating
>   schedule between two states: the fed state (the period of time during
>   which you eat) and the fasted state (the period of time when you do
>   not eat). This optimizes fat-burning periods when you're cutting, and
>   minimizes fat accumulation during a bulk due to the increase in
>   resting metabolism and utilizing body fat for fuel.
>
> You may drink water or consume extremely low-calorie beverages such as
>   herbal tea and black coffee during the fasted state, otherwise the
>   fasted state breaks and you enter the fed state.

Does chewing gum break intermittent fasting?

Answer (score 3):

Sugar free gum isn't a problem for intermittent fasting. Martin Berkhan, the creator of the popular Leangains IF program, allows you to have chewing gum, artificial sweeteners that are zero calories (so, diet soda, coffee with Splenda, etc), and he even says you can have 1-2 tbsp. of milk in your coffee, which amounts to more calories than a stick of gum.